# Next JS is loading external script but not executing them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my next app with the latest version 12.1.6, I'm trying to use bootstrap. I've added bootstrap CSS and js files from CDN to the head of **pages/_app.js** as below,

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Head from 'next/head';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <>
      <Head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Ogani, unica, creative, html"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
   );
  }

export default MyApp
```

**I used bootstrap Nav as below,**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've noticed bootstrap CSS is loaded and executing. But its JS is loading but not executing. Because the page isn't interactive menu isn't expanding and collapsing on click. Can anyone tell me what's a problem with it?

Comment: Have you tried deferring loading the javascript? It may be that the script is running before the DOM is loaded, and so none of the listeners are added

Comment: @Tom i added defer attr still it gives this error. Is there another way to deferring?

Comment: I think the answer below alludes to this. You need jquery to use the bootstrap javascript plugins

Comment: @Tom below answer doesn't work. Even you can try it. I got this error,

"ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at F (/Users/samiullah/Desktop/UkPillows/pillow-demo/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:7393)"

Comment: That's a different issue then. Bootstrap is being loaded before the DOM, so when bootstrap looks for the document it can't find it. This could either be because you need to defer loading but more likely because Next is trying to render the component serverside, where there is no DOM. You'll need to tell Next it needs to render this component clientside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was occurring because React/Next DOM operations were colliding with Jquery DOM operations. By deferring the jquery operations after react/next it worked. Just used useEffct hook to do jquery. It's solved [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37660#discussioncomment-2945201).

Replace the IIFE in mainW.js for:
// of course you perhaps want better names

```
function _runJQueryControls($) {
// rest of function
}
```

window.runJQueryControls = () => _runJQueryControls(jQuery);
Inside index.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window?.runJQueryControls();
  }, []);
```

In next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false, 
};
```

special thanks to [icyJoseph](https://github.com/icyJoseph) who helped.

Comment: It looks like this is specific to jquery with react, so it might be worth editing the question title to be more specific and discoverable. I can't do it myself as the edit queue is full atm

Answer (score 0):

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

const Layout = (props) => (
<div>
    <Head>
        {/* import external javascript */}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js"></script>
    </Head>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
);

export default Layout;
```

Comment: it's unable to import like this,

"ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at F (/Users/samiullah/Desktop/UkPillows/pillow-demo/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:7393)"

Comment: I just check the document exists there for boostrap.min.js but it's not able to import it like that.